# Плюсовать высоту к переменной jquery

Tags: jquery

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно в моем случае к исходной высоте блока приплюсовать произвольное количество PX ?

```
$(function() {
  var height = $('.about-main').height(); //получаем высоту одного элемента
  $('.form-wrap').height(height); //записываем высоту другому элементу
});
```

Мне нужно к переменной height добавить скажем ещё 50px .

Comment: А `+` поставить нельзя ? :)

Comment: height += 50; - так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А `+` поставить нельзя?

```
$(function() {
  var height = $('.about-main').height(); //получаем высоту одного элемента
  $('.form-wrap').height(height + 50); //записываем высоту другому элементу
});
```

Если же вы берёте высоту из CSS свойства, nо нужно будет преобразовать строку в число.

```
$(function() {
  var height = $('.about-main').css('height'); //получаем высоту одного элемента
  $('.form-wrap').height(parseFloat(height) + 50); //записываем высоту другому элементу
});
```